# How to get components of a panel in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, panel

I have a panel that holds some components of asp.net.I am generating this components(like dropdownlist, checkbox,textbox etc.) according to my data.

Example for dropdown :

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel comboBoxOlustur(ANKETQUESTIONBec bec)
{
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel p = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel();

    Table tb = new Table();
    TableRow tr = new TableRow();
    TableCell tdSoru = new TableCell(), tdComboBox = new TableCell();
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList cmb = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList();

    tdSoru.Text = bec.QUESTION;
    tdSoru.Width = 350;
    tdSoru.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Top;

    if (bec.WIDTH != null)
        cmb.Width = (short)bec.WIDTH;
    else
        cmb.Width = 200;
    cmb.Height = 18;
    //data operations
    QUESTIONSELECTIONDEFINITIONBlc blc = new QUESTIONSELECTIONDEFINITIONBlc();
    List<QUESTIONSELECTIONDEFINITIONBec> secenekler = blc.GetByAnketQueID(bec.ID,1);

    if (secenekler != null)
    {
        ListItem li;
        li = new ListItem();
        li.Value = "-1";
        li.Text = "--Seçiniz--";
        cmb.Items.Add(li);
        for (int i = 0; i < secenekler.Count; i++)
        {
            li = new ListItem();
            li.Value = secenekler[i].ID.ToString();
            li.Text = secenekler[i].NAME;

            cmb.Items.Add(li);
        }
    }
    //end of data operations
    tdComboBox.Controls.Add(cmb);
    tr.Cells.Add(tdSoru);
    tr.Cells.Add(tdComboBox);
    tb.Rows.Add(tr);
    p.Controls.Add(tb);

    return p;
}
```

In this point i want to reach to this dropdownlist to get value of it.How can i implement this?

Comment: [FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Something I'm working on now -- controls loaded based on database results -- they did it by using javascript on textchanged to save the value into a named hidden field... They put the values in JSON format and it uses a JavaScriptSerializer to read them in code behind. Right or not, I don't know.

Comment: Understood but i have service to save the data.I need to use it.So i need all datas of components collectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the best way is to appropriately name your controls and then use [FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You will probably need to use [FindControl recursively](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/asp/recursively-finding-controls) in order to easily search down multiple layers.

Depending on your needs, it may also make sense to declare a variable, or variable array, that tracks each of the controls added. It's possible that this approach could be used in a way that eliminates the need to search for the controls and would therefore be more efficient.

Comment: Count of components are dynamic.There can be 1 or 10 dropdown and text and checkbox.And i need all of this components not a specific one.So I think i can not use FindControl in this case.Am i wrong?

Comment: As I just said, you can use `FindControl()`. But as I also just said, you could simply store references to the variables instead. `List<Control>` could easily be used to store any number of variable references.

Answer (score 0):

I have used something like this to get all the child controls:

```
    private void GetAllControls(Control container, Type type)
    {
        foreach (Control control in container.Controls)
        {
            if (control.Controls.Count > 0)
            {
                GetAllControls(control, type);
            }

            if (control.GetType() == type) ControlList.Add(control);
        }
    }
```

and then do something like:

```
    this.GetAllControls(this.YourPanel, typeof(Button));
    this.GetAllControls(this.YourPanel, typeof(DropDownList));
    this.GetAllControls(this.YourPanel, typeof(TextBox));
    this.GetAllControls(this.YourPanel, typeof(CheckBox));
```